# Swift5. How to wait the request from another .swift file?

Tags: swift, semaphore, completion

[image]

There are 2 files:

1st - Network requests

2nd - ViewController, place where the result of `getCities() -> Array<String> { ... }`
should be called (at leasted could be checked with `print`

Using this to make a request:

```
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
      if (error != nil) {
        print(error as Any)
      } else { ...
}
```

***The problem:*** The result of the request couldn't be accessed by `UIViewController` until the finish of the request. The `list` of `UIViewController` is initiated too early.

P.S: Already tried

> semaphore

and

> group

but as for me, it works only for the same class/file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Don't ask, tell***

Use a completion handler to notify when the data are available. No semaphore, no group.

```
func getCities(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) { ... }
```

and

```
getCities { [weak self] cities in
    self?.list = cities
    print(cities)
    // do other stuff with received cities
}
```

Comment: This answer is the right solution. And keep in mind that if you need to do stuff with the list, you should do it inside the completion closure, not outside!